# Number of distinct colorings of a pyramid with a $p$-gon base (Burnside's Lemma)

Tags: combinatorics

Fix a prime $p$. Given a 3D "pyramid" with a $p$-gon base and one apex, how many rotationally distinct ways are there to color the faces of the pyramid using $c$ colors.

So I will use Burnside's lemma. Basically, there are $p$ symmetries (including the identity) of rotating around the axis connecting the apex with the center of the $p$-gon.

For the identity symetry, all $c^{p+1}$ face colorings are fixed.
For the remaining $p-1$ rotations, since $p$ is prime, then the color of the side faces must be the same. There is $c$ ways to choose the color of the side faces, and $c$ ways to choose the bottom face for a total of $(p-1)c^2$ fixed colorings across all $p-1$ remaining rotations.

Using Burnside lemma, the number of unique colorings is thus $\frac{1}{p}(c^{p+1}+(p-1)c^2)$.

Just as a sanity check, using Fermat's little theorem, $c^{p}\equiv c ~ \text{mod } p$ so $c^{p+1}-c^2 \equiv c^2 - c^2 \equiv 0 \text{ mod } p$ so this is indeed an integer. Does this look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the [necklace-counting formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial), since the number of ways to colour the triangular sides alone is equal to the number of $c$-colour $p$-bead necklaces:
$$\frac1p\sum_{d|p}\varphi(p/d)c^d=\frac1p((p-1)c+c^p)$$
Then the base can be coloured independently of the triangles, so the number of ways to colour the pyramid is the above number times $c$, which matches your result. So you are correct.

Comment: Thank you for the link and confirming.